# If you have vs if you had

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Is there a way to say

> if you had come to the meeting... ,

in other words the untrue condition, as opposed to :

> if you have come to the meeting... ,

the mere if clause? I used to think it was 假如, but dictionary examples suggest otherwise. For example:

> 假如有這必要, 就這麼幹吧。

EDIT:

If you use context to express this difference, please provide examples!
I would really appreciate an explanation in English (apart from the examples). My Chinese is basic and if I have to translate I only get the basics.

Comment: unreality of condition to be deduced from context, cf. e.g. 虚拟条件句的三种基本类型 http://www.yygrammar.com/Article/200802/202.html

Comment: find 100 example sentences for "If I had" also for "If I knew", etc. at jukuu

Comment: If you had is just 要是/如果你X了：if you had gone 你要是去了 / if you had listened 要是听了

Comment: @user3306356 So no difference to "if you have"?

Comment: @user6065 I have already used that engine, as well as others and the overwhelming majority of sentences reinforced my confusion, as I could not spot any difference.

Comment: see grammars，e。g。＂外国人实用汉语语法＂复句｜偏正复句｜（三）条件关系（conditional) vs。（四）假设关系（hypothetical)（三）一个分句（偏句）提出条件，另一个分句（正句）说明在这条件下产生的结果。例如：不管前排后排的话，你都替我买一张。只要是星期天，我就有时间。只有努力工作，才不辜负人民的培养。我一感冒，就发烧。（四）一个分句（偏句）提出一个假设的情况，另一个分句（正句）说明由假设情况产生的结果或推论。例如：要是你门有兴趣，我就陪你们去公园。大家如果有意见，就提出来。即使我病了，也一定参加这次大型的演出活动。便正复句中常用的关联词，列入如下：条件关系：不管。。。，都（也）。。。｜不论。。。，都（也）。。。｜无论。。。，都（也）。。。｜只要。。。，就。。。｜只有。。。，才。。。｜除非。。。｜才。。。｜一。。。，就。。。｜假设关系：要是。。。，就。。。｜如果。。。，就。。。｜假如。。。｜就。。。｜假使。。。，就。。。 Also search web using "英语虚拟语气怎么翻译" and  "how to translate subjunctive into Chinese"-> e.g.http://www.academypublication.com/issues/past/tpls/vol02/01/26.pdf

Comment: @user6065 the link is helpful, because the pdf is in English. Explanations that are only in Chinese, tend to be too difficult for me.

Comment: context: OP please provide contexts, which would not
distinguish between real and unreal conditions, in following examples, context does tell (more or less)
if you have come to the meeting, tell me who was there.
if you had come to the meeting, you could tell me who was there. In any case context often does tell.

Comment: @user6065 good point and helpful example! But there are also many examples, where someone used to thinking in European languages, does not see context. Such as the following dialogue: A: But he would have known about that! B: If he had come to the meatings.

Comment: @user6065 the problem may well come from the fact I am so used to having this device at my disposal, that I don't think of intelligently rephrasing sentences.

Comment: @user6065 would it be natural to operate like this: 這件事他原來該知道了！他要是去開會就知道了，只不過他沒去！ In other words, adding information about the irreality?

Comment: @Ludi have (already) would be more like 已经X | like I (have) already heard you 我已经听到了 vs if you had listened 你要是听了…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may consider "倘若", "假如", or "假使"

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000051670

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000089761

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000089751

but, the chinese language is "fuzzy", these terms do not absolutely indicate an untrue condition in the clause; they just merely imply such.

Comment: I would really appreciate an explanation in English (apart from the examples). My Chinese is basic and if I have to translate I only get the basics.